# 3 Modems HUAWEI E220 - Finding diferent data to make permanent USB Ports

Tags: usb, udev, 3g, huawei

I Have 3 Modems Huawei E220 USB connected on the same hub in the back USB Motherboard Ports.

After they are connected they work very well - no conflicts.
When I restart the system, all USB ports change!

I want to make permanent USB ports to these USB Modems. They are same vendor and model.

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
```

Note: For each USB Modem, Linux attributes two ports so:

```
1st modem - USBO & USB1
2nd modem - USB2 & USB3
3rd modem - USB4 & USB5

ls /dev/ttyUSB*
/dev/ttyUSB0  /dev/ttyUSB1  /dev/ttyUSB2  /dev/ttyUSB3  /dev/ttyUSB4  /dev/ttyUSB5
```

I suppose that's one for modem, other for CD-Rom Mass Storage device. When doing a `udevadm info`, I get this:

```
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB2 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB3 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB4 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.1"
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB5 | grep '{serial}'
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.1"
```

If serial are the same in the first two modems, which other data can be used to differ between these 3 modems?

Comment: Check `dmesg`, are the /dev/ttyUSBx devices created by the `usbserial` module? Try removing the module with `modprobe -r` and then reload it with `modprobe` - are the devices always created in the same order when you do this?